# Spring Boot + Mongo DB + Shiro configuration

Tags: spring, mongodb, apache, spring-boot, shiro

I am developing a web-based application in Spring boot and Mongo DB. Now I want to use Apache Shiro for Authentication and Authorisation.  Can somebody explain to me the procedure and how to establish a mongo db realm and where to mention the permission-user mapping? Thank You.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need three component

```
@Component
public class YourMongoConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "mongoTemplate")
    @DependsOn({ "lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" })
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate mt = new MongoTemplate(YOUR_CONFIGURATIOP_HERE);
        return mt;
    }
}
```

Then a MongoRealm

```
@Component("mongoRealm")
public class MongoRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {
    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public MongoRealm(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
        HashedCredentialsMatcher credentialsMatcher = new HashedCredentialsMatcher();
        credentialsMatcher.setHashAlgorithmName(Sha512Hash.ALGORITHM_NAME);
        credentialsMatcher.setHashIterations(53);
        setCredentialsMatcher(credentialsMatcher);
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
      // YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) 
throws AuthenticationException {
    // YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
    }
}
```

and finally a security manager

```
@Component("securityManager")
public class SecurityManager extends DefaultWebSecurityManager {
    @Autowired
    public SecurityManager(Realm mongoRealm, SessionDAO mongoSessionDAO) {
        super(mongoRealm);
        setRealm(mongoRealm);
        SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager();
        setSessionManager(sessionManager);
        sessionManager.setSessionDAO(mongoSessionDAO);
    }
}
```

From now on either Shiro will call your MongoRealm to validate login and permission and you will be able to hadle your collection with classes like

```
@Service
public class ONE_OF_YOUR_Services  {
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    protected List<T> getDocuments(Class<T> clazz, String collection) {
        return mongoTemplate.findAll(clazz, collection);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few MongoDB realms up on GitHub.  I don't want to link to them as haven't tried them out, but that would be your best place to start.